# How to add website (URL) shortcut to Ubuntu dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, 18.04, shortcuts, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I have created a shortcut to a website using [this guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/create-desktop-shortcut-website). Now I can see the shortcut on my desktop and it works fine. But I would like to add the shortcut on the side dock.

I can't seem to do it by drag and dropping, and there is no right-click option to "add to favourites".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following to create a launcher to open a website with Firefox and add it to Ubuntu dock.

1. Create a new file, say `MyWebsite.desktop` in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You can do that by running the following in Terminal

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/MyWebsite.desktop
   ```
2. Open this file with a text-editor, for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/MyWebsite.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following lines to this file and save the file

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Open XYZ website
   Terminal=false
   Name=XYZ website
   Exec=firefox website-URL
   Type=Application
   Icon=applications-internet
   NoDisplay=false
   ```

   In place of `website-URL` put the address you want to visit, for example `https://askubuntu.com` for Ask Ubuntu. Also edit the the `Comment=` and `Name=` fields accordingly.
4. Click on "*Activities*" at the top bar or "*Show Applications*" in the dock and search for "XYZ website". It should appear.
5. Right click on it and select "Add to favourites".

Comment: How would I use a custom icon, instead of `applications-internet`?

Comment: @jason Yes, you can do that by putting the full path to your preferred image in the `Icon=` line. For example, for the `MyIcon.png` file in your Pictures folder, use `Icon=/home/YOUR-USERNAME/Pictures/MyIcon.png`.